# Dynamic MVC Webgrid not binding as table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

In `Asp.net MVC` I am trying to pass Web Grid Control as dynamic from Controller via Viewbag but it is not rendering correctly in the View only the HTML tags are identified the MVC tags are shown as String only, The below is my code

```
string htmlSTR = "<div class=\"slideClass\" id=\"SlideDiv\">@grid3.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = \"WebGridID1\" }, tableStyle: \"table table-responsive table-bordered\", headerStyle: \"header_table\", rowStyle: \"row_table\", alternatingRowStyle: \"alt-row_table\", columns: grid3.Columns(grid3.Column(columnName: \"RouteNumber\", header: \"Route Number\", style: \"table-class\"))) </div>";

        htmlSTR = htmlSTR.TrimStart('"');
        htmlSTR = htmlSTR.TrimEnd('"');
        ViewBag.HtmlStr = htmlSTR;
```

and I am using `@Html.Raw` to bind the tag passed from Controller my View code is  `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.HtmlStr)`

But it is not binding correctly

```
<div class="slideClass" id="SlideDiv">@grid3.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "WebGridID1" }, tableStyle: "table table-responsive table-bordered", headerStyle: "header_table", rowStyle: "row_table", alternatingRowStyle: "alt-row_table", columns: grid3.Columns(grid3.Column(columnName: "RouteNumber", header: "Route Number", style: "table-class"))) </div>
```

The web grid is binding as Tag only not as table, kindly anyone point me what i have to change to bind the WebGrid as table instead of just tag

I have the web Grid mentioned in the View like

```
<div class="slideClass">

    <div>
        @grid2.GetHtml(
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "WebGridID1" },
            tableStyle: "table table-responsive table-bordered",
            headerStyle: "header_table",
            rowStyle: "row_table",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt-row_table",
            columns: grid1.Columns(
            grid2.Column(columnName: "RouteNumber", header: "Route Number", style: "table-class"),
            grid2.Column(columnName: "LoadReady", header: "Load Ready", style: "table-class"),
            grid2.Column(columnName: "SOD", header: "SOD", style: "table-class"),
            grid2.Column(columnName: "CutOff", header: "CutOff", style: "table-class"),
            grid2.Column(columnName: "EOD", header: "EOD", style: "table-class"),
            grid2.Column(columnName: "Settlement", header: "Settlement", style: "table-class"),
            grid2.Column(columnName: "Closed", header: "Closed", style: "table-class")))
    </div>
    @Html.Hidden("dir", grid2.SortDirection)
    @Html.Hidden("col", grid2.SortColumn)

</div>
```

Comment: Your just passing a string to the view!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need it to be formed dynamic so that I am passing it as dymanic string, Can you please guide me how to pass it

Comment: Generate it in the view as its designed for. And I do not know what your mean by _formed dynamic_.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i had mentioned the Web Grid in the View, but I need it as Dynamic because the Web Grid contains only 10 records in first div I need it to be slided to next div that contains the next set of Records in the next Grid

Comment: WebGrid supports paging to allow you to get the next set of records.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes I am aware that Web Grid allows Paging, is it possible to navigate to next page automatically without user intervention

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164724/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-rajesh).